# Django - Requiring Optional Form Field

Tags: django, forms, option-type

Somewhat new Django user here. I have a model and form that I intended to allow users to choose between uploading (posting, if using the model name) an image, text or both. Uploading is not allowed without an image despite the image attribute having blank=True and null=True. I then set the required=False on the image portion of the form, but this resulted in a

```
MultiValueDictKeyError
```

My model is:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploaded_images', blank=True, 
    null=True)
    text_post = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

My form is:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.FileField(required=False, label='Select an image 
    file', 
    help_text='Please select a photo to upload')
    text_post = forms.CharField(help_text="Please enter some text.") 
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('image', 'text_post',)
        exclude = ('author',)
```

My view is:

```
def posts(request, id=None):
    neighborhood = get_object_or_404(Neighborhood, id=id)
    form = PostForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = Post(image = request.FILES['image'])
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post = post.save()
            next = request.POST.get('next', '/')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-id')
        return render(request, 'posts.html', context = {'form':form, 
        'posts':posts, 'neighborhood':neighborhood})
```

and my form is:

```
    <form id="PostForm" method="post" action="/view/{{ neighborhood.id }}/posts/" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden }}
        {% endfor %}

        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.help_text }}
            {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.path }}">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you post more about the MultiValueDictKeyError? It's most likely because it's looking for something in a dict that isn't there, but what key and what dict might help us solve this faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you provide more information about the error, I'm going to take a crack at this and say that the issue is coming from this line in your view:

```
post = Post(image = request.FILES['image'])
```

Since you mentioned that an image can be considered optional, this would create an issue when you submit a valid text post, but your call to `request.FILES` will fail.

When you are unsure if a key exists in a dict (like you are in this case), you can use the `get` method to provide a default if it's not there. You could refactor this line to:

```
post = Post(image = request.FILES.get('image')
```

By default, the `get` method returns `None` when it can't find the key.

This all being said, your view is a bit confusing. You *stage to make* a Post with an image (you never called `.save()` on it), but then instantly discard it for the result of `form.save()` below. What's even more confusing is that the `save` call on the line `post = post.save()` returns `None`, as the `save` method on a model is void. (i.e. now `post == None`) I think you might need to reconsider some of these design patterns to save yourself some pain later on.

EDIT: Adding some clarification on the lines I mentioned:

Let's isolate these lines:

```
1   if form.is_valid():
2      post = Post(image = request.FILES['image'])
3      post = form.save(commit=False)
```

On line 2, what we are doing is making a new Post model instance with an image equal to the image we got from the request. So far so good. But in order to commit this to the database, I would still have to call `.save()` on the `post` variable. [[source]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects)

On line 3, the call to `form.save(...)` returns a new Post model instance (also not on the database, since you specified `commit=False`) But, notice that you set `post` equal to that result. Now the model instance from line 2 has been lost forever.

I'm not sure if you wanted line 2 to behave the way it did, but if you want to make something on the database in this manner, you can write

```
Post(image = request.FILES['image']).save()
```

*or*

```
post = Post.objects.create(image = request.FILES['image'])
```

In the first version, the return value is `None`, since `save` is a void function. In the second, the `create` method actually returns an instance of the created model, so that's the one I'd suggest you go with.

Comment: Thank line fixed it, it works perfectly now, thank you! I'm pretty new to Django so I don't completely understand your last paragraph. That being said, I am not making anything super complicated and am not making this project for anything important so even if my code is very convoluted, your fix will work for my needs. Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome to Django then! I added some clarification to help illustrate what I was trying to show; hope you can find it useful!

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much.